# tesseract with poor picture resolution

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am running fedora 11.

I seek to identify the characters indicating the date on a satellite image, but its resolution was (deliberately?) deteriorated.

The goal is to automate this procedure. For that I use ocr program **tesseract**.

It works perfectly on my PC with the scans, but in this case it does not work.

Here's what I did:

Address of the image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [meteo.pf](http://www.meteo.pf/bulletins/satellites/societeir.jpg))</sub>

I convert in `tiff` format (used by `tesseract, (bpp ok)`)

I use tesseract: `tesseract societeir.tif test`, but no output.

When I increase the image scaling, the `ocr` online work, but `tesseract` not.

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion,

Since the date on the image is most likely going to be in the same position and of the same dimension, you can try to cut it out and save it as another image using an image processing tool. I normally would use gimp, but leptonica, imagemagick are other tools that I can think of. The recognition should be better on the new image

Answer (score 0):

Copy the date region into memory, run enhancements on it then run the OCR against it?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I copied the date region, but how run enhancements on the picture before to run the OCR against it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi everyone,
I have not managed to identify the date of this image with tesseract. So I watched another ocr software: cuneiform and it works perfectly.
See you soon,

Comment: Sorry for being blunt. I meant you could attempt to remove any pixels which aren't exactly character pixels ie, set a threshold of perhaps really dark pixels and extract them because they're most likely the characters.